# x264 parameters configuration

Tags: ffmpeg, sip, asterisk, h.264, x264

I need to configure x264 to reproduce the below parameters.

The configuration was extracted using Elecard Stream Analyzer from the first keyframe received from a legacy SIP phone h264 encoder. It is mission critical to reproduce it in software to keep compatibility with other sip clients.

All the information I have are the parameters below.

Is it possible at least to get close to the original ?

Thanks a lot.

```
0x00000000 H264 Sequence Parameter Set  
    profile_idc = 66 (PROFILE_IDC_Baseline)  
    constraint_set0_flag = 1  
    constraint_set1_flag = 0  
    constraint_set2_flag = 0  
    constraint_set3_flag = 0  
    constraint_set4_flag = 0  
    constraint_set5_flag = 0  
    reserved_zero_2bits = 0  
    level_idc = 12  
    seq_parameter_set_id = 4  
    log2_max_frame_num_minus4 = 4  
    pic_order_cnt_type = 2  
    num_ref_frames = 1  
    gaps_in_frame_num_value_allowed_flag = 0  
    pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 = 19 (320)  
    pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 = 14 (240)  
    frame_mbs_only_flag = 1  
    direct_8x8_inference_flag = 1  
    frame_cropping_flag = 0  
    vui_parameters_present_flag = 0  

0x0000000C H264 Picture Parameter Set  
    pic_parameter_set_id = 4  
    seq_parameter_set_id = 4  
    entropy_coding_mode_flag = 0  
    pic_order_present_flag = 0  
    num_slice_groups_minus1 = 0  
    num_ref_idx_L0_active_minus1 = 0  
    num_ref_idx_L1_active_minus1 = 0  
    weighted_pred_flag = 0  
    weighted_bipred_idc = 0  
    pic_init_qp_minus26 = 2  
    pic_init_qs_minus26 = 0  
    chroma_qp_index_offset = 0  
    deblocking_filter_control_present_flag = 1  
    constrained_intra_pred_flag = 0  
    redundant_pic_cnt_present_flag = 0  

0x00000014 H264 I slice #1 { frame_num = 0 }  
    first_mb_in_slice = 0  
    slice_type = 2  
    pic_parameter_set_id = 4  
    frame_num = 0  
    idr_pic_id = 4  
    dec_ref_pic_marking():  
    if(IdrPicFlag)  
        no_output_of_prior_pics_flag = 0  
        long_term_reference_flag = 0  
slice_qp_delta = 0  
disable_deblocking_filter_idc = 0  
    slice_alpha_c0_offset_div2 = 0  
    slice_beta_offset_div2 = 0  

0x00000591 H264 I slice #1 { frame_num = 0 }  
    first_mb_in_slice = 126  
    slice_type = 2  
    pic_parameter_set_id = 4  
    frame_num = 0  
    idr_pic_id = 4  
    dec_ref_pic_marking():  
        if(IdrPicFlag)  
            no_output_of_prior_pics_flag = 0  
            long_term_reference_flag = 0  
    slice_qp_delta = 0  
    disable_deblocking_filter_idc = 0  
    slice_alpha_c0_offset_div2 = 0  
    slice_beta_offset_div2 = 0  

0x00000B34 H264 I slice #1 { frame_num = 0 }  
    first_mb_in_slice = 201  
    slice_type = 2  
    pic_parameter_set_id = 4  
    frame_num = 0  
    idr_pic_id = 4  
    dec_ref_pic_marking():  
        if(IdrPicFlag)  
            no_output_of_prior_pics_flag = 0  
            long_term_reference_flag = 0  
    slice_qp_delta = 0  
    disable_deblocking_filter_idc = 0  
    slice_alpha_c0_offset_div2 = 0  
    slice_beta_offset_div2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, H264 is isn't supported by Asterisk at all - at least not at the transcoding level, only passthru (if at all).